# SQL How to summarize integer/numeric values on different rows

Tags: sql, sum

I am trying to merge integer and numeric values from different SQL rows within the same table into one row so that they are summarized.

```
  | ID | Count | Total Payment
1 | 1  |     5 |         10.99
2 | 1  |     3 |          4.86
3 | 2  |     8 |         19.88
4 | 2  |     2 |         15.99
5 | 2  |     5 |          8.45
6 | 3  |     4 |         12.98
7 | 3  |    10 |         40.42
```

As such I want to summarize the above rows into the below rows.

```
  | ID | Count | Total Payment
1 | 1  |     8 |         15.85
2 | 2  |    15 |         44.32
3 | 3  |    14 |         53.40
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `sum()` and `group by`. This should be covered by any sql tutoria, and there are many

Comment: SELECT [ID], [Count]=SUM([Count]), [Total payment]=SUM([Total payment] FROM [TableName] GROUP BY [ID]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you HonyBadger and Mathieu Guindon.

The correct code was:

```
SELECT [id], SUM([count]), SUM([total_payment])
FROM [table_name]
GROUP BY [id]
ORDER BY [count], [total_payment];
```